# Merging Jpg file to Pdf Stream

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, itext

Here is my issue: I'm trying to read JPG files from a folder and convert them to one PDF file for example if in my folder I have 1).Hello.jpg 2). World.jpg I want to grab those files and combined it to a one PDF file so the result will be
newPDF.pdf

I'm reading the images correctly from the folder adding them to the document but it's not creating the new PDF file in the folder. How can I solve this??

Here is my code:

```vb
'!=Orginally after setting all the files in the folder we need to read the path from the session file.
'!= After reading the path we need to read each file from the folder and generate one pdf file.
Dim attachmentsFolder As String = "E:/IRAttachments/PSC/2013/2/IR-7264"
Dim fileName As String = String.Concat("IR_7264(", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff").ToString(), ").pdf")
Dim finalPathName As String = String.Concat(attachmentsFolder, "/", fileName)
'!= Step 2). read the pdf/images from folder and merge them to a one pdf file.
Dim files As New List(Of String)()
Dim readerList As New List(Of PdfReader)()
m_HashTableIRAttachments = New Hashtable
m_DictionaryEntryIRAttachments = New DictionaryEntry
Dim fileExtentionType As String = String.Empty
Dim doc As Document = New Document

For Each filePath As String In Directory.GetFiles(attachmentsFolder)
    fileExtentionType = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf("."))

    If fileExtentionType = ".jpg" Then '# Get the extension type 
        Dim document As New Document()
        Using stream = New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream)
            document.Open()
            Using imageStream = New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
                Dim image__1 = Image.GetInstance(imageStream)
                document.Add(image__1)
                Dim pdfFile As String = finalPathName
            End Using
            document.Close()
        End Using

        'PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + fileName, FileMode.Create))
        'doc.Open()
        'doc.Add(New Paragraph("Hello World"))
        'Dim myDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 100.0F, 0.0F)
        'Dim pdfFile As String = finalPathName
        'Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDoc, New FileStream(pdfFile, FileMode.Create))
        'myDoc.Open()
        'Dim para As New Paragraph("Let's write some text before inserting image.")
        'Dim myImage As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(filePath)
        'myImage.ScaleToFit(300.0F, 250.0F)
        'myImage.SpacingBefore = 50.0F
        'myImage.SpacingAfter = 10.0F
        'myImage.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
        'myDoc.Add(para)
        'myDoc.Add(myImage)
        'myDoc.Close()
        'doc.Close()

    Else
        '# Means it's a pdf and not a jpg file.
        Dim pdfReader1 As New PdfReader(filePath)
        readerList.Add(pdfReader1)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the `Stream` for your PDF file, you are using the `fileName` variable, which is only the name, not the full path.  It is likely that the PDF is being created - just not where you are expecting it to be.  You probably want to use `finalPathName` instead:

```vb
Using stream = New FileStream(finalPathName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
```

I would also recommend you take a look at the methods available on the [`System.IO.Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, and use them when constructing file paths and getting the file extension, e.g.

```vb
Dim finalPathName As String = Path.Combine(attachmentsFolder, fileName)
'...
fileExtentionType = Path.GetExtension(filePath)
' etc.
```

**EDIT**

It looks like you are also overwriting the PDF file for each image file, while I would imagine you want all of the images in one PDF file.  Your loop for the images should probably be inside the `Using stream = ...` block (e.g. between `document.Open()` and `document.Close()`).